# What does ".1M/250" mean as a capacitor rating?

Tags: capacitor

I'm not very familiar with capacitor markings, and I'm trying to understand what exactly this one means. I'm guessing .1M indicates 0.1 microfarads with 20% tolerance, but I have no idea what the /250 means.
I don't have any documentation for it since I just pulled it out of a dimmer switch.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a 0.1uF +/-20% mylar film capacitor rated for 250VDC. That is a typical capacitance, type of capacitor, and voltage rating for the capacitor used in a dimmer. The voltage rating is a DC rating.

[image]

The capacitor actually only sees the diac breakdown voltage (typically 30-40 volts) plus a volt or two for the triac gate.

The "M" does not stand for microfarads- rather it is a tolerance code.

- J = +/-5%
- K = +/-10%
- M = +/-20%

---

In light dimmers, sometimes the diac is integrated into the triac as [one unit](http://www.littelfuse.com/data/en/Data_Sheets/Littelfuse_Thyristor_QxxxxLTx.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. Though this particular dimmer doesn't contain a diac.

Comment: Sometimes the diac is integrated into the triac as one unit. I'll add a link to an appropriate datasheet. Often the part number starts with a "Q" in that case (for Quadrac).